Gauss Divergence Theorem Question in my exam stuck at integration part
I did this but got stuck at the integration
apply gauss divergence theorem to evaluate Doubleint(F.ndS) where F=4x^3i-x^2yj+x^2zk and S is the surface of cylinder x^2+y^2=a^2 bounded by the place z=0 to z=b
I am stuck in the integration part and now I'm questioning wheather I did it right or wrong till there can any kind soul answer?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you added your steps, it would help people tell you where you're right/wrong
